# Prove that T is onto but not one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra

$$T: C[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ defined by $$T(f) = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$$

Prove that $T$ is onto (with a general argument) but not one-to-one (with a specific counter-example).

I think that I can do the one-to-one part, but I'm a bit confused as to how to prove it's onto. I only know how to prove onto by rank with matrices.

Hope that makes sense, this is my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 2):

Take $y \in \mathbb{R}$, you have to find a function  $f \in C[-1,1]$ such that $T(f)=y$.

Then pick $$f(x)=\frac{y}{2}$$

Clearly:

$$T(f)=\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx =\int_{-1}^1 \frac{y}{2} dx=\frac{y}{2}\int_{-1}^1 1 dx=\frac{y}{2} x \ \biggl|_{x=-1}^{x=1}=\frac{y}{2}(1--1)=y$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got from f(x)=y/2 to T(f)=y. Could you elaborate? Sorry, it's been a long time since I've done integrals and I can't make connections between your steps.

Comment: @Madeline ok I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is not one-to-one because $T(x^n) = 0$ for all odd $n$.